# How to remove the box surrounding the text inside a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton

[this image shows the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3foyQ.png)

When I run `JFrame` a small box is surrounding the text in the focused `JButton` (See the picture attached)

How can I remove that box?

Comment: How is the user supposed to know which button is focused? See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property is called `focusPainted` and you can disable it by:
`jbutton.setFocusPainted(false);`